# Suppose $a_{i}+1=a_{i}q, \forall i \in \mathbb N$, show by induction that if $ q\neq1$, $a_{1}+...+a_{n}=\dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_{1}}{q-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

### Suppose $a_{i}+1=a_{i}q, \forall i \in \mathbb N$, show by induction that if $ q\neq1$, $a_{1}+...+a_{n}=\dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_{1}}{q-1}, \forall n \in \mathbb N$

Let $P(n)$ be the proposition we want to prove.

For $P(1)$ we have:
$a_{1}=\dfrac{a_{2}-a_{1}}{q-1}=\dfrac{a_{1}q-a_{1}}{q-1}$, and i dont know how to continue.

Comment: Do you mean $a_{i+1}$ instead of $a_i + 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that $P(n)$ is ok then just add $a_{n+1}$ to both sides of $P(n)$ and you will have:

$$a_{1} +... + a_{n+1} =  \dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_{1}}{q-1}  + a_{n+1} $$

$$a_{1} +... + a_{n+1} =  \dfrac{a_{n+1}-a_{1}}{q-1}  + \dfrac{a_{n+1} * (q-1)}{q-1}$$

$$a_{1} +... + a_{n+1} =  \dfrac{a_{n+1}*q-a_{1}}{q-1}  $$

$$a_{1} +... + a_{n+1} =  \dfrac{a_{n+2}-a_{1}}{q-1}$$

which shows that $ P(n)$ after adding $a_{n+1} $ proves $ P(n+1)$

Comment: ohh now i see, thank you very much for your time and help¡¡¡